# Login screen on main display

Tags: release-loki, display, system

first of all i love your system and i dont this to be take as critique, just would love to have this issue fix.

So Im using my laptop as a dock and I work on my external monitor. I always use display option that only my external monitor is up and monitor on laptop is off. This works perfectly fine except login screen, where it displays content onto my laptop screen. Is there some configuration Im missing, or is this broken?

Love your OS guys, keep up the good work.

Comment: would be nice if the bug will be fixed soon! I have the same problem. workaround...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this using [this gist by Ryan Miller](https://gist.github.com/RyanMillerC/c48d9f63f8fe386b22a7da18cf6913d2) and changing LightDM configuration file. All you need is this script (remember to change `PRIMARY_DISPLAY` in first, according to comment):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# { 2017-07-02 16:20 }
# { Ryan Miller | ryan@abstractfoc.us }
# { /usr/local/bin/correct-screen-pantheon-greeter }
# 
# Set correct primary monitor for login screen when lightdm greeter starts up on Elementary OS.

# Change this variable to your primary display (Run 'xrandr -q' to see available displays)
PRIMARY_DISPLAY='HDMI-0'

# Get list of connected monitors
x_out=$(xrandr -q | grep -e '\( \)connected' | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }')

# Safety - Check if PRIMARY_DISPLAY is connected; if not, bail out of script
[[ $(grep ${PRIMARY_DISPLAY} <<< ${x_out}) ]] || exit 0

# Iterate over x_out and disable all monitors except for PRIMARY_DISPLAY
for monitor in ${x_out[@]} ; do
    if [[ ${monitor} = ${PRIMARY_DISPLAY} ]] ; then
        xrandr --output ${monitor} --primary
    else
        xrandr --output ${monitor} --off
    fi
done
```

and LightDM config file setting location of script:

```
#{ /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf }
[Seat:*]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/correct-screen-pantheon-greeter
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue on my 2 monitor desktop setup. The greeter/login appears on the non-primary monitor for login, but then corrects itself once logged in. Annoying, but a minor issue since it's so easy to work around.

Not an answer, but there appears to be an open issue in the LightDM/Pantheon Greeter GitHub page here: [Greeter does not respect displays settings](https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/65)

I'm not sure if this is a fork of the original LightDM or not, or what the up-streaming circumstances are, but it's a know issue. Hopefully someone will fix it someday.